# Select random Integers from 2 arrays until condition is true

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I wonder what's the most efficient way to write a function that takes two arrays of random integers and terminates when a pair of matching Integers is found.

In the following example there are two arrays, one larger then the other.
The larger array contains the potential dividents, the smaller array the divisors. 
I'd like the function to calculate until it has found a pair of divident and divisor that are divisible without remainder.

EXAMPLE:

```
var listDivident = _.shuffle(_.range(1, 101));
var listDivisor = _.shufle(_.range(1, 11));

randomMatch = function (listDivident, listDivisor) {
   /* until ((listDivident % listDivisor !== "undefined") 
      && (listDivident % listDivisor === 0) {
        ...
      }
   */
    return {
        matchDivident: matchDivident,
        matchDivisor: matchDivisor
    };
};
```

Is there something like an "until" function or construct in JS?

Thanks for your help!
Vin

Comment: In stead of thinking "Do XXX until..." think of it like "While it isn't done, continue".

Comment: You want a `while` loop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your arrays are very large, you can simply generate all valid pairs first and then pick a random one:

```
var pairs = [];

_.each(listDivident, function(a) {
    _.each(listDivisor, function(b) {
        if(!(a % b))
            pairs.push([a, b])
    })
});

result = _.shuffle(pairs)[0];
```

Comment: thanks! i used `_.sample(pairs)` for the result so it's even shorter :)

Answer (score 1):

What you call "until" can be achieved by looping *until* you find what you need:

```
var listDivident = _.shuffle(_.range(1, 101));
var listDivisor = _.shufle(_.range(1, 11));

randomMatch = function (listDivident, listDivisor) {
    var i = 0,
        found = false,
        dividentLength = listDivident.length,
        divisorLength = listDivisor.length,
        matchDivident = null,
        matchDivisor = null;
    while (!found && i < dividentLength && i < divisorLength) {
        if (listDivident[i] % listDivisor[i] === 0) {
            matchDivident = listDivident[i];
            matchDivisor = listDivisor[i];
            found = true;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return {
        matchDivident: matchDivident,
        matchDivisor: matchDivisor
    };
};
```

**EDIT:** After that, just call the `randomMatch()` with the whole arrays:

```
alert(randomMatch(listDivident, listDivisor));
```

Comment: thanks for your copious answer! i'll stick georg's response since its short an lean.